# Consistency Principle implies Compactness Principle for Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, set-theory, propositional-calculus

I'm currently reading through "Combinatorial Set Theory" by Lorenz J. Halbeisen.

In Chapter 5 the author claims that the Consistency Principle implies the Compactness Principle for Propositional Logic. By Consistency Principle he means the following:

> Let $S$ be a set and let $B$ be a set of binary functions (i.e., with
> values 0 or 1) defined on finite subsets of $S$. We say that $B$ is a
> binary mess on $S$ if $B$ satisfies the following properties:
>
> - For each finite set $P \subseteq S$, there is a function $g \in B$ such that dom($g$)$=P$, i.e., $g$ is defined on $P$.
> - For each $g \in B$ and each finite set $P \subseteq S$, the restriction $g|_P$ belongs to $B$.
>
> Let $f$ be a binary function on $S$ and let $B$ be a binary mess on
> $S$. Then $f$ is **consistent with $B$** if for every finite set $P
>  \subseteq S$, $f|_P \in B$.
>
> *Consistency Principle.* For every binary mess $B$ on a set $S$, there exists a binary function $f$ on $S$ which is consistent with $B$.

This terminology does not seem to be very widespread (i.e. a quick google-search yielded no relevant results). He then proceeds to prove the aforementioned implication as follows

> Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulae of Propositional Logic and let $S \subseteq \mathcal P$ be the set of propositional variables which
> appear in formulae of $\Sigma$. Assume that every finite subset of
> $\Sigma$ is satisfiable, i.e., for every finite subset $\Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma$ there is a realisation $g_{\Sigma_0} : S_{\Sigma_0}
>  \to \{0, 1\}$ which satisfies $\Sigma_0$ , where $S_{\Sigma_0}$
> denotes the set of propositional variables which appear in formulae of
> $\Sigma_0$. Let $$B_\Sigma:=\{ g_{\Sigma_0}|_P : \Sigma_0 \in
>  \text{fin}(\Sigma)\land P\subseteq S_{\Sigma_0}\}.$$ Then $B_\Sigma$
> is obviously a binary mess and by Consistency Principle there exists a
> binary function $f$ on $S$ which is consistent with $B_\Sigma$. Now,
> $f$ is a realisation of $\Sigma$ and therefore $\Sigma$ is
> satisfiable.

I understand why $B_\Sigma$ is a binary mess (this is indeed easily checked). I however do not understand, why f satisfies $\Sigma$. For that we need to check, that f satisfies any formula $\varphi \in \Sigma$, but I don't see, how having $f$ be consistent with the binary mess $B_\Sigma$ helps exactly.

This is my first time posting on Stackexchange, so please feel free to point out, if this question is not well-formulated or something like that.

EDIT:

I've had time to think about this problem and now I think I found a counterexample. Let $S = \{a\}$ and $\varphi = a, \psi = a \lor \lnot a$ as well as $\Sigma = \{\varphi, \psi\}$. Now clearly $\Sigma$ is (finitely) satisfiable and by definition of $B_\Sigma$ we have $B_\Sigma = \{a \mapsto 1, a \mapsto 0\}$ since $a \mapsto 0$ satisfies $\{\psi\}$. Now $a \mapsto 0$ is consistent with the binary mess $B_\Sigma$ but doesn't satisfy $\Sigma$. What am I missing here?

Also fixed some typos.

EDIT 2:

So I have convinced myself, that the proof cited above is actually not completely correct. The mistake however is easily fixed and I will leave this for future reference:

Instead define

$$B_\Sigma = \{g : P \to 2 | P \in \text{fin}(S) \land \forall \varphi \in \Sigma : \text{var}(\varphi) \subseteq P \implies g(\varphi) = 1\}$$

We need to put a little for effort into showing that this is a binary mess, but now a consistent function $f$ will actually satisfy $\Sigma$.

Comment: Is that $>$ sign in $P > \subseteq S$ a typo, or is it some notation I'm not familiar with? And what are the two unicode characters between "Let" and the definition of $B_\Sigma$? They only show up as the generic box for me. (Best to use mathjax, not esoteric unicode characters, in posts.)

Comment: The term "binary mess" dates back to the original proof in 1950s (or 1960s? I forget right now). In much more modern set theoretic terms, this is a $\mathcal P_\omega(X)$-tree (the kind of $\cal P_\kappa(\lambda)$-trees used to characterise strong- and supercompactness cardinals).